# how to Catch exception in Jackson Spring , org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Using Spring framework.. and Jackson to map Json to classes..

```
  {name:'abc', marks:'100'}
```

-

```
class student{
      String name;
      int marks;
    }
```

-

Now this is getting mapped properly... But, if i modify JSON to

```
 {name:'abc', marks:'ten'}
```

*org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON* exception is thrown... 
***Now, i need to catch this exception and return some result. How to catch the exception.***

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="xxxxxx",produces="application/json",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String mymethod(@RequestBody Student studentData, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        //controller code
    }
```

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231323/jersey-jackson-how-to-catch-json-mapping-exception

Comment: @SachinGupta thanks ... exactly what i want ..